# Are requests for more ideomatic code a target for migration to Code Review?

Tags: discussion, migration, code-review-se

Let's assume we have a question that contains:

1. a small snippet of code that does not stand as a whole program (a single function, etc.)
2. no "problem" specified by the OP, only a request for "more ideomatic code", whatever that means in your language of choice.

I do not know if such a question follows Stack Overflow rules but I wish to know if it would be appropriate to flag such a question for migration to Code Review. I flagged such a question for manual migration, but the flag is still pending after almost 2 days, so I'm here posting on meta.

Question purposely not linked to avoid the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/235225/358302).

Comment: They won't want to import such 'questions'.  They will be turned back at border security.  Repeated attempts might lead to diplomatic incidents or open warfare.

Comment: If the code in the question is not well explained, I'd be reluctant to migrate it. It's hard to evaluate that without the actual question.

Comment: I see a fair number of [tag:python] questions asking if code can be made more "pythonic".  I don't mind these questions at all.  Usually what they're really asking is "Does python have a language feature that does this for me/is there a more readable way to write this".  Often the answer is yes, and I think SO is an appropriate place for those questions. I imagine other languages face similar problems.

Comment: Depend on quality. there must be a check list for CR migration somewhere.

Comment: [A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5777/31562) - Does this answer your questions?